# Compare 2 multi-dimensional arrays with php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

My goal is to take a 2 arrays 1 coming from Google Calendar the other from a Google Spread sheet. The arrays are both formatted the same except that the Calendar array has a ID field.

My multidimensional Google Spread Sheet array contains a number of arrays that looks like :

```
array (
'startDate' => '2013-03-29',
'endDate' => '2013-03-29',
'startTime' => '08:00',
'endTime' => '20:00',
'title' => 'Ext2 Joe',
 )
```

My multidimensional Google Calendar array contains a number of arrays looks like:

```
 array (
 'startDate' => '2013-03-29',
 'endDate' => '2013-03-29',
 'startTime' => '08:00',
 'endTime' => '20:00',
 'title' => 'Ext2 Joe',
 'id' => 'enmjke5qpjs41q93vi8tibp85k',
  )
```

Here is the code I am using. It misses lot of events that exist in both. I have been struggling with this and reformatting it different way and can not seem to get it to remove the duplicates and leave me with just an array `$final_array` that contains what is left. So I can then add those pieces to the Google calendar as they don't already exist there.

```
 $k=0;
 $match=0;
 $remove_events=array_values($all_events);
 $add_final_array=$final_array;
 foreach($final_array as $array_final)
 {

$h=0;

foreach ($all_events as $loop_all_events)
{   
        if ($array_final["startDate"]==$loop_all_events["startDate"]){
            if ($array_final["endDate"]==$loop_all_events["endDate"]) {
                if ($array_final["title"]==$loop_all_events["title"]) {
                    if($array_final["startTime"]==$loop_all_events["startTime"]) 
 {


                unset($add_final_array[$k]);
                unset($remove_events[$h]);
                $remove_events=array_values($remove_events);                    
                $match++;
            } } } } 



$h++;           
}


$k++;                      

 }
```

Comment: Did you try [array_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)? Or what happens if you merge them together? Will there ever be conflict data that you care about or do you just want to merge one into the other?

Comment: I did try array diff but it came up with no matches. I placed the array diff inside of the foreach ($all_events as $loop_all_events) and compared $loop_all_events to $array_final but it came up empty. When I tried to print_r the result.

Comment: I think part of why array diff didn't work was because I didn't have a single set of unique data to compare. Were I need to compare all 4 elements in the array to see if it is unique. That or I had it formated incorrectly I did try it a couple ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$array1 = array (
'startDate' => '2013-03-29',
'endDate' => '2013-03-29',
'startTime' => '08:00',
'endTime' => '20:00',
'title' => 'Ext2 Joe',
 );

 $array2 = array (
 'startDate' => '2013-03-29',
 'endDate' => '2013-03-29',
 'startTime' => '08:00',
 'endTime' => '20:00',
 'title' => 'Ext2 Joe',
 'id' => 'enmjke5qpjs41q93vi8tibp85k',
  );

  $diff = my_array_diff($array1, $array2);
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($diff);

  function my_array_diff($array1, $array2){
     $diff1 = array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2);
     $diff2 = array_diff_assoc($array2, $array1);
     $diff = array_merge($diff1, $diff2);

     return $diff;

  }
?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => enmjke5qpjs41q93vi8tibp85k
)
```

Comment: The data I am comparing is the starttime, stoptime, startdate, and title. The id is just the id from google calendar that if I need to delete the event then that is the id I use. So that I know will only exist in the one array. I can't get it to correctly compare every array in the 1st  multi-dimensional array every array in the 2nd multi-dimensional array ignoring the id field since it's only in the one array.I list the formate of the individual arrays that are just one of many in the multi-dimensional arrays just so everyone could see how my format was.

Comment: Wasn't exactly what I needed as I was already un-setting the id but I was able to get it working thank you.